# How to test integration with the Twilio API using Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio-api

I integrated [Twilio-Ruby](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) into my Ruby and created some methods that post to the API using that gem.

Here's an example of a method in my TwilioMessage model in Rails:

```
  def message(recepient_number, message_body = INSTRUCTIONS, phone_number = '++18889990000')
    account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create({
                                        :from => phone_number,
                                        :to => recepient_number,
                                        :body => message_body
                                    })
  end
```

I tried integrating [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) with my Minitest suite but I'm just not sure where to begin with that.

I tried using WebMock to block outgoing requests and stubbing it with:

```
stub_request(
        :post, "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[ACCOUNT_ID]/Messages.json"
    ).to_return(status: 200)
```

in my setup block.

Then, in my test, I have:

```
  test "send message" do
    TwilioMessage.expects(:message).with('+18889990000').returns(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  end
```

In my test_helper file I have it set to only allow local connections.

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

But, I received:

```
Minitest::Assertion: not all expectations were satisfied
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: TwilioMessage(id: integer, from_number: string, to_number: string, message_body: text, message_type: string, twilio_contact_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime).send_message('+18889990000')
```

I tried looking through the Specs for the Twilio-Ruby gem but haven't had any luck.

Does someone have an example and explanation of how they've tested or would test this? I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: From your output, it appears that send_message wasn't invoked.  One approach, you can take is to set WebMock to allow connections to the internet, write your test so that it passes while calling the Twilio API.  After it passes, disable the net connect and stub the requests so that you still have a passing test but are not calling Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Ruby Gem [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) for the test. Turns outs that it's super easy to setup.

At the top of the test file, I added:

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = "test/vcr/cassettes"
  config.hook_into :webmock
end
```

VCR lets the call go through the first time and records the response to a fixture file specified in the `config.cassette_library_dir` line above.

Then, in the actual test, I used `VCR.use_cassette` to record the successful call. I used a valid phone number to send to in order to verify it was working as well. You'll see a sample phone number in the test below. Be sure to change that if you use this example.

```
 test 'send message' do
    VCR.use_cassette("send_sms") do
      message = TwilioMessage.new.message('+18880007777')
      assert_nil message.error_code
    end
  end
```

I found the [RailsCast episode on VCR](http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr?autoplay=true) to be extremely helpful here.